# Viewing my package documentation with devtools

Tags: r, devtools

I'm using devtools to handle a package I'm working on.

If I run `R` and then run

```
library(devtools)
devtools:::load_all()
```

I am able to view my packages documentation.

However, I'm trying to create an alias to automate the launching of R (it's actually going into a Makefile). So I created a file "load.R" with those two lines, then run

```
R_PROFILE=load.R R
```

I get my package loaded properly (e.g. I can do `mypackage:::` and see all functions) but I cannot access my help files.

(If I start R and run `source("load.R")` I can see my help files, so I'm confident it's not a typo or something else foolish.)

I'm thinking it might have something to do with the timing of the `load_all` call; I believe passing a `R_PROFILE` runs the code before the session becomes interactive. So, alternatively, is there a way to run something like

```
R -e 'source("load.R")'
```

and have it stay interactive instead of quitting after the code terminates?

Thanks.

Comment: What if you put that line of code into your `.Rprofile` instead?

Comment: Same result as `R_PROFILE=load.R`; the package loads but the help won't.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution myself, though I'd appreciate any additional ideas, as I'm a bit uncomfortable mucking about with environments like this.

`devtools` appropriates `help` and `?` by creating a new environment defining versions of the functions which can see my package's help files, and attaching this environment. By the time it gets called interactively, the `search()` stack has already filled out with the default environments, specifically the `package:utils` environment from the built in package `utils` (where `help` and `?` exist). When `attach`ing a new environment, it gets added to the top of the `search()` stack (just behind `.GlobalEnv`.

However, R_PROFILE loads earlier than those base packages being loaded, so when using `R_PROFILE=load.R`, the `devtools` environment is lower on the `search()` stack, so `help` and `?` stick with their default versions.

The solution I have is to update `load.R` to have

```
library(utils)
library(devtools)
load_all()
```

This forces `utils` to load earlier, and before `devtools`, so that the order of environments is as desired.